# Expo : Background and Closed Application

Tags: expo, background-process

To run a function in background in Expo is TaskManager , but work only if app is in FOREGROUND.

How to run a function in background (With App in background ) AND app closed in Expo ?

Example : an easy timer clock ...every second run a function

Thanks

Comment: Did you try BackgroundFetch: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/    stopOnTerminate (boolean) -- Whether to stop receiving background fetch events after user terminates the app. Defaults to true. (Android only)

Comment: @Oleg Expo documentation has a known issue that it will not work on app termination
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/#known-issues